# Not able to add policies in SAM template

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I am working on SAM template for publishing my Application in AWS Serverless repository.
But when I try to add policies for my lambda it shows me error:
Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Errors: Resource with id [SyncPostDataFromSfLambda] is invalid. Only policy templates are supported in 'Policies' property.

Below is the example for my SAM template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description": "Deployment",
    "Resources": {
        "SyncPostDataToSfLambda": {
            "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Handler": "index.handler",
                "FunctionName": "myLambdaFunction",
                "CodeUri": "s3 URL",
                "Runtime": "nodejs6.10",
                "MemorySize": 512,
                "Policies": [
                    "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
                ],
                "Events": {
                    "PostResource": {
                        "Type": "Api",
                        "Properties": {
                            "RestApiId": {
                                "Ref": "API"
                            },
                            "Path": "/apipath",
                            "Method": "post"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

As of today (2018-10-09), SAM template already supports inline policy document.

Here is an example:-

```
Resources:
  SomeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Sid: SSMDescribeParametersPolicy
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - ssm:DescribeParameters
          Resource: '*'
        - Sid: SSMGetParameterPolicy
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - ssm:GetParameters
          - ssm:GetParameter
          Resource: '*'
```

References:

1. [AWS::Serverless::Function's **Policies** property on AWS SAM Specification](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#properties)
2. [Related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/224)

Comment: This is what I was looking for exactly, but for SNS. thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here's the full list of [policy templates](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/policy_templates/all_policy_templates.yaml) from the official repo example.

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Policies:

        - SQSPollerPolicy:
            QueueName: name

        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: name

        - CloudWatchPutMetricPolicy: {}

        - EC2DescribePolicy: {}

        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: name

        - DynamoDBReadPolicy:
            TableName: name

        - SESSendBouncePolicy:
            IdentityName: name

        - ElasticsearchHttpPostPolicy:
            DomainName: name

        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: name

        - S3CrudPolicy:
            BucketName: name

        - AMIDescribePolicy: {}

        - CloudFormationDescribeStacksPolicy: {}

        - RekognitionDetectOnlyPolicy: {}

        - RekognitionNoDataAccessPolicy:
            CollectionId: id

        - RekognitionReadPolicy:
            CollectionId: id

        - RekognitionWriteOnlyAccessPolicy:
            CollectionId: id

        - RekognitionLabelsPolicy: {}

        - SQSSendMessagePolicy:
            QueueName: name

        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
            TopicName: name

        - VPCAccessPolicy: {}

        - DynamoDBStreamReadPolicy:
            TableName: name
            StreamName: name

        - KinesisStreamReadPolicy:
            StreamName: name

        - SESCrudPolicy:
            IdentityName: name

        - SNSCrudPolicy:
            TopicName: name

        - KinesisCrudPolicy:
            StreamName: name

        - KMSDecryptPolicy:
            KeyId: keyId

        - SESBulkTemplatedCrudPolicy:
            IdentityName: name

        - SESEmailTemplateCrudPolicy: {}

        - FilterLogEventsPolicy:
            LogGroupName: name

        - StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy:
            StateMachineName: name
```

Comment: How to add multiple resources for a single policy? Let's say I want to add multiple S3 buckets?

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot. 
But where can we find all of these informations in AWS documentation ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that currently only **SAM Policy Templates** can be used.

AWS maintains the authoritative information/overview of SAM Policy Templates here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/using-aws-sam.html

This document also states that, if you need further AWS Resources and/or Policy Templates, you should contact the [AWS Support](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/).

A short overview and example of how to use them can be found here: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/policy_templates/all_policy_templates.yaml

Here's the overview of currently supported SAM Policy Templates at the time of posting this answer:

- SQSPollerPolicy (provides sqs:DeleteMessage, sqs:ReceiveMessage)
- LambdaInvokePolicy (provides lambda:InvokeFunction)
- CloudWatchPutMetricPolicy (provides cloudwatch:PutMetricData)
- EC2DescribePolicy (provides ec2:DescribeRegions, ec2:DescribeInstances)
- DynamoDBCrudPolicy (provides dynamodb:GetItem, dynamodb:DeleteItem, dynamodb:PutItem, dynamodb:Scan, dynamodb:Query, dynamodb:UpdateItem, dynamodb:BatchWriteItem, dynamodb:BatchGetItem)
- DynamoDBReadPolicy (provides dynamodb:GetItem, dynamodb:Scan, dynamodb:Query, dynamodb:BatchGetItem)
- SESSendBouncePolicy (provides ses:SendBounce)
- ElasticsearchHttpPostPolicy (provides es:ESHttpPost)
- S3ReadPolicy (provides s3:GetObject, s3:ListBucket, s3:GetBucketLocation, s3:GetObjectVersion, s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration)
- S3CrudPolicy (provides s3:GetObject, s3:ListBucket, s3:GetBucketLocation, s3:GetObjectVersion, s3:PutObject, s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration, s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration)
- AMIDescribePolicy (provides ec2:DescribeImages)
- CloudFormationDescribeStacksPolicy (provides cloudformation:DescribeStacks)
- RekognitionNoDataAccessPolicy (provides rekognition:CompareFaces, rekognition:DetectFaces, rekognition:DetectLabels, rekognition:DetectModerationLabels)
- RekognitionReadPolicy (provides rekognition:ListCollections, rekognition:ListFaces, rekognition:SearchFaces, rekognition:SearchFacesByImage)
- RekognitionWriteOnlyAccessPolicy (provides rekognition:CreateCollection, rekognition:IndexFaces)
- SQSSendMessagePolicy (provides sqs:SendMessage*)
- SNSPublishMessagePolicy (provides sns:Publish)
- VPCAccessPolicy (provides ec2:CreateNetworkInterface, ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface, ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces, ec2:DetachNetworkInterface)
- DynamoDBStreamReadPolicy (provides dynamodb:DescribeStream, dynamodb:GetRecords, dynamodb:GetShardIterator, dynamodb:ListStreams)
- KinesisStreamReadPolicy (provides kinesis:ListStreams, kinesis:DescribeLimits)
- SESCrudPolicy (provides ses:GetIdentityVerificationAttributes, ses:SendEmail, ses:VerifyEmailIdentity)
- SNSCrudPolicy (provides sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic, sns:CreateTopic, sns:SetTopicAttributes, sns:Subscribe, sns:Publish)
- KinesisCrudPolicy (provides kinesis:AddTagsToStream, kinesis:CreateStream, kinesis:DecreaseStreamRetentionPeriod, kinesis:DeleteStream, kinesis:DescribeStream, kinesis:GetShardIterator, kinesis:IncreaseStreamRetentionPeriod, kinesis:ListTagsForStream, kinesis:MergeShards, kinesis:PutRecord, kinesis:PutRecords, kinesis:SplitShard, kinesis:RemoveTagsFromStream)
- KMSDecryptPolicy (provides kms:Decrypt)

**Almost any of those Policy Templates have to be configured.** Please read the AWS documentation (links above) about how to configure these templates.

Comment: I want to give full DynamoDB access, Please guide me if there is a way to give custom permissions to the lambda

Comment: Thanks Oliver, But I have to give permission to read dynamodb streams but I don't know the table name in prior. It is upto the user which table he want to connect with my lambda. Can you help me on this? Thank for your time

Comment: I don't think, that this is possible out of the box right now. But you can add roles/permissions manually after creating the lambda function (by using IAM).

Comment: I suggest you read up more on how this site actually works. Start with [answer], especially [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) on why answers are deleted. Stack Overflow is not "the web" but a specialist Q&A site, with specific rules and no tolerance for users who fail to read and abide by the rules.