# Could not get the syntax of policy definition in SAM template resource(serverless function)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-serverless, aws-sam

Policy definition of *AWS managed policy*(`AWSLambdaExecute`) is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "logs:*" ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject" ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

But the [AWS_documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template.html#serverless-sam-template-function) gives a sample serverless function using the same policy name `AWSLambdaExecute`, as shown below:

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: index.js
    Runtime: nodejs8.10
    CodeUri: 's3://my-code-bucket/my-function.zip'
    Description: Creates thumbnails of uploaded images
    MemorySize: 1024
    Timeout: 15
    Policies:
     - AWSLambdaExecute # Managed Policy
     - Version: '2012-10-17' # Policy Document
       Statement:
         - Effect: Allow
           Action:
             - s3:GetObject
             - s3:GetObjectACL
           Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*'
```

---

that does not match with the above definition.

**Edit:**

Below is the sample function's execution role... I do not see AWS mananged execution role names(such as `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`). Because my understanding is,  `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` role should be assigned to Lambda, by default

[image]

---

Are we overriding the policy definition of `AWSLambdaExecute` in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are specifying policies, you are basically building an execution role your lambda function.

`Policies` is a list of policies because role can include multiple policies in it.

This line

```
- AWSLambdaExecute # Managed Policy
```

states that the lambda function that you are creating should include this AWS managed policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "logs:*" ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject" ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following lines:

```
- Version: '2012-10-17' # Policy Document
       Statement:
         - Effect: Allow
           Action:
             - s3:GetObject
             - s3:GetObjectACL
           Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*'
```

are specifying next policy that you want to include in your lambda execution role.

**Are we overriding the policy definition of AWSLambdaExecute in this example?**

No, we are adding multiple policies to lambda execution role, one of them is AWS managed policy and one is our own custom policy. So the lambda function will have permissions defined in both of them. Or more precisely, union of those policies will be made and lambda function will have permissions defined by that union, meaning that if one of the policies allows lambda function to do something and the other denies the same thing, the result will be that the action will be denied.

Comment: What is the name of that lambda execution role? Is it `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole ` ?

Comment: Yes, the one that is adding permissions to CloudWatch logs is called `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`, but if you are asking what is the name of the new role that is created by cloudformation then the name is unique each time you create a new stack something like `lambda-test-ThumbnailFunctionRole-LWUCKA5ULR2A`.

Comment: Matus , I think the question here is: Does SAM create a new (randomly named) execution role for each lambda function specified in the template? Do you know this?

Comment: Yup, I have realized that :) And yes, CF will create new role.

Comment: And if you want to find the exact name of your role, you can go to CloudFormation -> select the newly created stack -> select resources -> look for the role (logical ID of the role will be `NameOfTheFunctionRole` which will have physical ID associated with it)

Comment: How do I see the list of roles assigned to my Lambda function? after deploy

Comment: Your lambda function can only have one role at a time. If you are asking how to see list of permissions of the new role then you can either go to IAM and search for that new role or you can go to Lambda service -> select that lambda function -> click on the key icon in designer which will show function policy on the left and execution role on the right (the one that contains those permissions)

Comment: Query edited with screenshot... to my question in previous comment.

Comment: That picture shows the name of that new role which has union of permissions constructed from the custom policy and the managed policy defined in your SAM template.

Comment: Little follow up on this... https://stackoverflow.com/q/57029782/3317808

Comment: My own custom policy is creating inline policy but to customer managed policy... https://stackoverflow.com/q/57029985/3317808

Answer (score 1):

I think what your *Policies* attribute does, is:

- attaches the managed policy *AWSLambdaExecute* and then
- creates an inline policy for your execution role which grants the s3 permissions *s3:GetObject* and *s3:PutObject*. There is another SO post which indicates that SAM now supports defining inline policies. [1]

Defining inline policies does not overwrite anything.
You can have multiple different types of policies attached to a single identity (e.g. IAM user or role). [2]

#### References

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719165/10473469
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my preferred approach (omitting other fields for clarity):

```yaml
 MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy # AWS Managed Policy
        - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess # AWS Managed Policy
        - AWSLambdaExecute # AWS Managed Policy
        - Version: '2012-10-17' # Policy Document to allow S3 access
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
             Action:
               - s3:GetObject
               - s3:GetObjectACL
             Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*'
```