# Lambda - How to create customer managed policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

## Background:

IAM policies can be created in two ways:

- Managed policies(newer way)

  - AWS managed policies
  - Customer managed policies
- Inline policies(older way)

---

Below SAM template is creating inline policy:

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.LambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Sid: AccessToS3Policy
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetObjectACL
          Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*'
```

---

in the resultant role, as shown below:

```
{
   "roleName": "somestack-HelloWorldFunctionRole-AAAAAAAA",
   "policies": [
   {
      "document": {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:GetObjectACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "AccessToS3Policy"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "HelloWorldFunctionRolePolicy0",
      "type": "inline"
    },
    .....
   ]
 }
```

---

In case of Lambda function,

1) How to create Customer managed policy?

2) How inline policy different from Customer managed policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using this syntax in your SAM template

```
Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Sid: AccessToS3Policy
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetObjectACL
          Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*'
```

It will automatically create inline policy. If you want to create customer managed policy instead of inline policy then you need to define the policy as a separate `Resource` in you template and reference it in `policies`. Or you can create the role outside of the template (e.g. via AWS console) and reference that policy, in the same way you would reference AWS managed policy.

**How inline policy different from Customer managed policy?**

I wouldn't really say that inline policy is the old way of doing things. The only difference between inline policy and customer managed policy is that inline policy cannot be reused (you cannot assign inline policy to two or more entities). But this can often be handy if you need a specific policy that you are not planning to reuse in future.

Comment: Can you refer me to some syntax? that can be used in SAM template.. this one... https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/76#issuecomment-276755605

Comment: But policy(inline or managed) is part of existing new role.. Where are we restricting on assigning the role to one or more entities?

Comment: Here you can check how to define IAM policy resource in you template, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html. Then you can use intrinsic function `Ref` in `Policies` to reference logical ID of the policy.

Comment: It is not the role that can be assigned only to one entity, that role can be assigned to (assumed by) any number of trusted entities but the underlying policy cannot, if it is inline policy. If you go to your console -> IAM policies, you will not find that policy there.

Comment: I think you referred to inline policy(`AWS::IAM::Policy`)... Am looking for AWS doc that refers to managed policy something like this.... https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/76#issuecomment-276755605 . Correct me...

Comment: You are right, the correct resource type is `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy`

Comment: So... inline policy can be assigned to only one role or one user or one group... Is that the understanding?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can assign it to one of those and that is it. If you wanted to assign the same policy to another entity, you would again need to create new inline policy with the same permissions. But in such case, it would be more reasonable to create it as a managed policy.

Comment: One supple... How this permission boundary different from Managed policy or Inline policy?  Let me know... if I need to add new question... In Lambda function case scenario.. We can restrict access through our customer managed policy, why again permission boundary?

Comment: I am not sure which policies we are comparing now. If you have something specific on your mind that is not part of the original question then it is better to start a new question.

Comment: I have a related question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044845/iam-policy-how-to-reference-resources