# IAM policy - How to reference resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Below is the policy template created to restrict any `Principal` to do only below actions:

```
Resources:
  MyPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: RulesToCreateUpdatePolicy
      ManagedPolicyName: some-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:

          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "iam:CreatePolicy"
              - "iam:DeletePolicy"
              - "iam:CreatePolicyVersion"
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/xyz-lambda-*"
```

---

on a policy resource that starts with name `xyz-lambda-`.

This policy is assigned to EC2 host, with a role.

---

Does this policy name(like `xyz-lambda-*`) supposed to be already exist in AWS, before uploading this policy in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you are specifying resource in your policy document, that resource doesn't need to exists at all.

If you take into consideration this action

```
iam:CreatePolicy
```

together with your resource, what it does is that it grants necessary permissions to create policy with that particular name `xyz-lambda-*`. It wouldn't make much of sense to require existence of such resource if the policy is granting permissions to create it in the first place.

When you consider the delete action

```
iam:DeletePolicy
```

if the resource doesn't exist then it does nothing. Once you create policy with the appropriate name, you will be able to delete it but it doesn't matter whether the policy existed before this ManagedPolicy was created or after or you have deleted and recreated policy with such name any number of times.

Lastly, since you have stated that this policy is attached to EC2 role then it should work without errors. But I would still recommend to grant `iam:ListPolicies` permission for any resource (policy) discovery that could be performed by an application running on EC2 instance. If you don't allow this action in your policy, your application will not be able to list policies and you would have to design some error prone workaround based on guessing or a strict naming scheme.

Comment: Aah got it in your line: "make much of sense to require existence"

Answer (score 1):

Policy name is not important. Resources unique by ARN only. IAM Resources unique within AWS account an if u don't create this resource before it's ok